# Is there a way to remove a close vote?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

Not sure this is the correct place to ask, but is it possible to remove ones close vote, after say the user has reworded the question or provided clarification on the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope.  Though you can vote to reopen after it is closed. And both types of votes (close and reopen) expire after two days.

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes/33949#33949).

Comment: ah expiring after 2 days .. gotcha